# How to display d3 elements on a gridster box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create an area chart using `d3`, using this array:

```
var jsonResObj = {
               initial_hours: [
                  1800, 1700, 1030, 1130, 950, 1249, 1225, 1821, 1250,
                  1505, 38, 130, 1520, 1600, 1330, 1930, 1806, 1535
                ]
              };
```

The code for the axis and the chart is here:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
        width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        days = jsonResObj.initial_hours.length;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, days])
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(jsonResObj.initial_hours)])
    .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

    var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(days); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(jsonResObj.initial_hours); });

    var svg = d3.select("#box1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("path")
    .datum(jsonResObj)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

My `Gridster` box:

```
<li data-sizey="3" data-sizex="3" data-col="3" data-row="1">
    <div class="gridster-box" id="box1">
        <div class="handle-resize"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I load my page, only the axes show up and the `area` selector
is `0px * 0px`

How do I draw these area charts in my `gridster` box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform the data so each data point is an object containing the x and y properties and can properly be accessed by your area function.

The way you have it currently, there is no way for d3 to know which day or hour an area data point is referring to.

See code below showing changes to the area function to refer to the day and hour properties of the data object passed via function(d). The data transformation is right after the svg variable declaration. Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw1pcg8r/1/) of the solution.

```
var jsonResObj = {
           initial_hours: [
              1800, 1700, 1030, 1130, 950, 1249, 1225, 1821, 1250,1505, 38, 130, 1520, 1600, 1330, 1930, 1806, 1535
            ]
          };

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
    width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    days = jsonResObj.initial_hours.length;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, days])
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(jsonResObj.initial_hours)])
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.day); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.hour); });

var svg = d3.select("#box1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [];
jsonResObj.initial_hours.forEach(function(d,i){
        data.push({day: i, hour: d})
});

svg.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("class", "area")
.attr("d", area);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: I see it works, but I do not understand how in the area variable, the x and y read the day and hour, since I do not have it declarated.

Is the data transformation function always necessary in these cases?

Comment: The area variable is a function using whatever data is passed to it. When its declared all it knows is that some data would be passed to it and it would use data.day for the x-axis, and data.hour for the y-axis. We create such a data object with 'day' and 'hour' keys and pass it to this function which only needs the data when its called, not when it is initialized. I wouldn't say such transformations are always necessary but it makes sense to me to hold such related values together in an object as opposed to say two arrays and have to track positions of related items as the function iterates.